# defining variables with type in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Is this valid ?

```
def CallableStatement st

try {
 ...     
 st = sqlConn.prepareCall("call....")
 ...
}
```

what I'm really worried about is can you specify type and also use def at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this valid ?

Yes and no....

Yes, because the compiler will happily compile and execute the code above, but no, because it really doesn't make any sense to type something as `def` and also assign it as an explicit type. Basically what you're saying is "this can have any type, but it must be a `CallableStatement`". In my opinion, the definition above *should* generate a compiler error.

In practice this definition:

```
def CallableStatement st
```

Appears to be identical to:

```
CallableStatement st
```

As the following illustrates:

```
class Foo { 
  def List l;
}


new Foo().l = new ArrayList()  // this works
new Foo().l = "ddd"  // this throws a GroovyCastException
```